ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'x' where x is a module suppose to be a shared lib
I have a project with three modules - one, two and three. one and two are stand-alone services and three is the common lib that will be used by one and two. When I tried to run docker-compose up --build at the root folder, both the module one and two containers failed to start with error log
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'three'

Below is the structure
/root-folder
│
├── one
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
│
├── two
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
│
├── three
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── setup.py
│
└── docker-compose.yaml

The docker-compose.yaml file is as below
version: '3.8'

services:
  one:
    container_name: container-one
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./one/Dockerfile
    image: one:latest  
    ports:
      - "8881:8881"
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=development

  two:
    container_name: container-two
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./two/Dockerfile
    image: two:latest  
    ports:
      - "8882:8882"
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=development 

And Dockerfile for one and two are
FROM python:3.12-slim AS builder

WORKDIR /build

COPY /one/requirements.txt /build/     # ("COPY /two/requirements.txt /build/" for Dockerfile of module two)

RUN python -m venv /opt/venv \
    && /opt/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel \
    && /opt/venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt

FROM python:3.12-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /opt/venv /opt/venv

ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

COPY /one /app                        # ("COPY /two /app" for Dockerfile of module two)
COPY /three /three

RUN pip install /three && pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "main.py"]

For three is
FROM python:3.12-slim AS builder

WORKDIR /build

COPY requirements.txt /build/

RUN python -m venv /opt/venv \
    && /opt/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel \
    && /opt/venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt

FROM python:3.12-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /opt/venv /opt/venv

ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

COPY . .

RUN pip install -e .

and the setup.py for module three is
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='three',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(include=['*']), 
    install_requires=[
        'avro-python3==1.10.2',  
    ],
    zip_safe=False,
)

Please help.

You do this:
COPY /one /app
COPY /three /three
But it should be this:
COPY ./one /app
COPY ./three /three
Not sure if this fixes your issue though

Hi @KenjiBailly, thanks for your reply. However, it still gave me the same issue even after I modified the Dockerfile in one and two as you suggested.
